# Google autocomplete callback pointing to a function inside a Javascript module

Tags: javascript, html, es6-modules

I am getting started with the Google autocomplete API where the following code is included in the script tag. However, the callback function initAutocomplete is inside a module and I am not able to call it.

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=APIKEYGOESHERE&libraries=places&callback=initAutocomplete" async defer></script>
```

Could someone kindly advise on the best approach for this?
Alternatively, how would I format the contents of the script tag to sit inside a js module?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: In my case I had to put the initAutocomplete() function at the bottom of the page, inside the body tag, to make it work.

Comment: Hi Manashree - In my case, the initAutocomplete() function has to sit inside a JS module because I am using it to trigger other functions I have imported. So I can't have it inside the body tag.

Comment: You should show where you are inserting the script in the HTML file